# Tracking real life object in Virtual Reality

Tags: virtual-reality, meta-quest

I'm building a VR game (in Unity) in which a user uses a real-life steering wheel to drive around. I want them to be able to grab the steering wheel in real life, while the virtual counter part of this steering wheel is located on the 'correct' location in the VR headset. I.e. if the steering wheel is located half a meter from the VR headset in real-life, it is placed half a meter from the user's point of view in the simulation.

How can I make sure of this, without asking the user to play around with settings? Ideally, I would want the headset to be able to detect and locate the real-life steering wheel, and relay this location to my software. The software would then simply place the steering-wheel in the correct location.

I found some old forum-posts (~2016) talking about IR trackers, but I couldn't really find anything definitive. I am using a Meta Quest 3, which does have cameras, so it might be able to detect some sort of (IR) tracker? What would be a good method of doing this?

Comment: [Checking the official Quest developer forums](https://communityforums.atmeta.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?q=track%20object&collapse_discussion=true), there seem to be requests for this kind of feature as recently as last spring, but no guidance for how to implement it, so it might not be supported at present.

Comment: This is the depth estimation problem. You can achieve it by asking user to input the necessary data (camera specs, steering wheel size, etc), then calculate the steering wheel distance after locating it, or by using existing artificial intelligence that transform 2d data to 3d (i haven't know any AI that do this), or ask user to use external hardware to calculate distance. In https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_Quest_3 it was said that Meta Quest 3 only have one depth sensor located in the middle, which isn't enough to track steering wheel position especially if it is not in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

If your object is static non-moving, You can use Meta scene understanding to identify an object in their list, query for it in your application to find the location of the object and its bounding box. Meta currently doesn't have a solutions for computer vision related tasks for identifying real world objects because they don't allow camera stream.

[This blog does a good job in describing scene understanding](https://blog.learnxr.io/xr-development/meta-scene-understanding-with-unity)

I Would identify the steering wheel as a plant set the bounding box around the wheel, then in my unity app query for the plant to get the location.